# Entity Framework 5 Spatial Data And WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, entity-framework-5

I am currently trying to migrate an existing data layer to EF5.

Before migration, we were not storing geographic data in SQL spatial data structures; with EF now supporting spatial data, we are refactoring our code.

We are using Self Tracking Entities to exchange data between a silverlight client and a WCF service. The problem is that, since DbGeometry type can not be serialized, it is not possible to share our entities with the client.

I hope I am missing a point, thus a direct solution exists; on the other hand, I would be glad if someone can provide a workaround. (we can use DTOs, but a huge refactor may be needed.)

Comment: The docs say that `DbGeometry` has `SerializableAttribute` -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeometry.aspx ?

Comment: well, this is strange I have read that it is not serializable. On the otherhand, the problem persists as there is no way to share entities between client and server; I could not find a dll including DbGeometry type in silverlight.

Comment: DTO's may be your only option?

Comment: If you are using Sql Server the EF spatial types are actually backed by Sql Server spatial types. If you just need the types you can install them by installing the Sql Server Feature pack (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065). What you are after is Microsoft.SqlServer.Types. I don't know if these types would work in Silverlight though. Also this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117008/net-4-5-beta-dbgeography-notimplementedexception may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact there are two options:
the first one is obvious; using DTO to transfer data.

The second answer is a bit complicated; but I resolved the problem using the following approach:

First I decompiled the `DbGeometry` and `DbGeography` classes using reflector. Then, I  created an assembly in silverlight named as `System.Data.Spatial` and added decompiled classes to this assembly. Next was the hard part; I deleted all code which can not be compiled in Silverlight (such as DB connection related codes).

Then I have ended up with a Silverlight spatial data library which supports only two basic functions:
Get Data as WKT and save data as WKT. These two functions are enough to consume related data and save it back using a WCF service.