# Spatial DataReader and Wrapping Providers in EF6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

To get my head around the new style of wrapping providers in EF6 I have put a quick sample together but I am struggling when it comes to the spatial data reader.

The exception I get is

```
Specified type is not registered on the target server.System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.
```

Below is the code... if anyone could help me identify what is wrong it would be much appreciated.

Model

```
public class TestEF6DataSource : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MattShape> MattShapes { get; set; }
}

public class MattShape
{
    [Key]
    public int MattShapeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DbGeometry GeoShape { get; set; }
}
```

Migrations

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TestEF6DataSource>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(TestEF6DataSource context)
    {
        context.MattShapes.AddOrUpdate(
            m => m.MattShapeId,
            new MattShape { MattShapeId = 1, GeoShape = DbGeometry.FromText("POLYGON ((1843503.54576196 5743170.10983084, 1843627.97736856 5743384.66544795, 1843557.59765677 5743393.36080548, 1843362.48753989 5743417.46230251, 1843361.11361057 5743417.63180584, 1843358.43835504 5743418.34609364, 1843355.88774656 5743419.42171531, 1843353.50983276 5743420.83971631, 1843352.42925232 5743421.70492403, 1843051.20263201 5743663.02873092, 1843050.40246141 5743663.67014246, 1843048.94101245 5743665.10920791, 1843047.63448048 5743666.69052689, 1843046.49589101 5743668.39810608, 1843045.53827419 5743670.21195005, 1843044.77165509 5743672.11506149, 1843044.20306302 5743674.085437, 1843043.83952263 5743676.10507526, 1843043.76129276 5743677.12752066, 1843043.68306289 5743678.14996605, 1843043.73770804 5743680.20110406, 1843044.00148376 5743682.23547495, 1843044.47141291 5743684.23206429, 1843045.14351779 5743686.16985646, 1843046.01081798 5743688.02883293, 1843047.06232975 5743689.78997102, 1843048.28907043 5743691.4342504, 1843048.98356169 5743692.18944876, 1843227.79751488 5743886.66320856, 1843370.49789926 5744041.86289133, 1843211.63121968 5744181.85544627, 1843210.88004919 5744182.51692323, 1843209.51761462 5744183.9841149, 1843208.30811202 5744185.57955102, 1843207.26456693 5744187.28723829, 1843206.3960028 5744189.09117878, 1843205.7124471 5744190.97237412, 1843205.219924 5744192.91282186, 1843204.92345948 5744194.89251733, 1843204.87426871 5744195.89198485, 1843204.82507793 5744196.89145237, 1843204.92780195 5744198.89162105, 1843205.22865675 5744200.87000785, 1843205.72666166 5744202.80960272, 1843206.41483744 5744204.68938653, 1843207.28720192 5744206.49134292, 1843208.33477247 5744208.1964515, 1843209.548563 5744209.78869344, 1843210.23107302 5744210.52086848, 1843362.82471731 5744374.04062576, 1843521.47199211 5744544.04810409, 1843522.80403726 5744545.4754015, 1843525.96805836 5744547.76127718, 1843529.51504843 5744549.39225262, 1843533.31000687 5744550.30713888, 1843537.21089892 5744550.47075254, 1843541.06965155 5744549.87791897, 1843544.74116062 5744548.55148175, 1843548.0862959 5744546.53930455, 1843549.53359801 5744545.22929443, 1844144.05575353 5744006.88500424, 1844169.18539025 5743983.5857433, 1844170.63172801 5743982.24570703, 1844172.94368956 5743979.05168963, 1844174.58874644 5743975.46769333, 1844175.50270343 5743971.63171704, 1844175.57703662 5743969.66175839, 1844175.90023907 5743961.04656371, 1844175.97457214 5743959.07660504, 1844175.5375125 5743956.34865246, 1844175.73760702 5743956.35989003, 1844177.73678424 5743956.27215751, 1844179.71618148 5743955.98629701, 1844181.65778673 5743955.50428874, 1844183.54258396 5743954.83111332, 1844185.34955492 5743953.97274958, 1844187.06267936 5743952.93918428, 1844188.66293657 5743951.73940016, 1844189.4001205 5743951.0628946, 1844199.50135086 5743941.78666567, 1844213.84039117 5743928.61827538, 1844215.28972002 5743927.28724656, 1844217.61466838 5743924.11025168, 1844219.27671508 5743920.54228211, 1844219.35211419 5743920.23420591, 1844219.64432342 5743920.18952037, 1844223.35289272 5743918.83709466, 1844226.72609487 5743916.78591001, 1844228.17943055 5743915.45088351, 1844242.51647028 5743902.28248667, 1844253.4640615 5743892.22881894, 1844254.21126251 5743891.54231917, 1844255.55975269 5743890.02607475, 1844256.74730665 5743888.38057548, 1844257.7628975 5743886.62381815, 1844258.59449784 5743884.7737984, 1844259.23508291 5743882.84851766, 1844259.67862504 5743880.86898012, 1844259.91909887 5743878.85418888, 1844259.93628859 5743877.83967025, 1844259.97595609 5743875.56550898, 1844263.40172796 5743875.62750567, 1844265.30771411 5743875.66172916, 1844269.06349335 5743875.01072919, 1844272.62898191 5743873.66213868, 1844275.87505338 5743871.66483413, 1844277.28130799 5743870.37777789, 1844293.26093854 5743855.74349582, 1844293.42794675 5743855.81372633, 1844297.16404668 5743856.59746499, 1844300.98202765 5743856.66191644, 1844304.74282077 5743856.00191699, 1844308.31032266 5743854.64332287, 1844311.55740795 5743852.63501293, 1844312.96166863 5743851.34195079, 1844366.48183378 5743802.05767893, 1844367.94418863 5743800.71065451, 1844370.28118872 5743797.49464845, 1844371.94128574 5743793.88164838, 1844372.85727827 5743790.01365209, 1844372.92562613 5743788.02667511, 1844372.99397396 5743786.03969812, 1844372.34618617 5743782.11786455, 1844370.93975308 5743778.39926161, 1844368.82953432 5743775.03003047, 1844367.46347793 5743773.58568301, 1844311.37120972 5743714.28931765, 1844598.56152946 5743510.53102903, 1844599.82925634 5743509.63101582, 1844602.05797441 5743507.46143768, 1844603.92386625 5743504.97427061, 1844605.3828408 5743502.22749453, 1844606.40080074 5743499.28910624, 1844606.95165187 5743496.22811234, 1844607.02330055 5743493.11953884, 1844606.61466136 5743490.03642345, 1844606.1741564 5743488.54511938, 1844558.82589522 5743328.15393844, 1844545.72733704 5743226.88587176, 1844545.50322096 5743225.15769254, 1844544.46552075 5743221.83172273, 1844542.86925421 5743218.73523003, 1844540.76133973 5743215.96031771, 1844539.4830261 5743214.77621074, 1844471.09777847 5743151.40250573, 1844439.20618072 5743078.48089337, 1844438.77908038 5743077.50588234, 1844437.72365546 5743075.65568148, 1844436.47798437 5743073.92932726, 1844435.05605492 5743072.34384485, 1844433.47485308 5743070.9192645, 1844431.75037123 5743069.6696121, 1844429.90260273 5743068.60991869, 1844427.95354434 5743067.75321654, 1844426.93937208 5743067.42987565, 1844347.35981 5743042.11069952, 1844087.70346261 5742812.08654871, 1844086.51504258 5742811.03362263, 1844083.8365753 5742809.32963639, 1844080.92346809 5742808.06961547, 1844077.84672431 5742807.28365755, 1844074.68536083 5742806.99386527, 1844071.51841542 5742807.20433173, 1844068.42393221 5742807.91314573, 1844065.47897565 5742809.10038539, 1844064.11929846 5742809.91825389, 1843510.54101528 5743142.92357374, 1843508.86995706 5743143.92917723, 1843505.97737608 5743146.54822255, 1843503.64650513 5743149.67618338, 1843501.9625264 5743153.19509576, 1843500.99062767 5743156.97296537, 1843500.76599237 5743160.86775796, 1843501.29879528 5743164.7334084, 1843502.56719526 5743168.42281405, 1843503.54576196 5743170.10983084))") },
            new MattShape { MattShapeId = 2, GeoShape = DbGeometry.FromText("POLYGON ((1767189.79377487 5904558.30070561, 1767215.1492355 5904492.43152391, 1767215.22475214 5904445.62448443, 1767192.95192382 5904443.13290794, 1767196.09833442 5904422.95242129, 1767174.81164464 5904414.75687878, 1767129.42429366 5904534.9388636, 1767189.79377487 5904558.30070561))") }
            );

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Wrappers

```
public class TestDbProviderServices : DbProviderServices
{
    private DbProviderServices InnerProviderServices { get; set; }

    public TestDbProviderServices(DbProviderServices inner)
    {
        InnerProviderServices = inner;
    }

    protected override DbCommandDefinition CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
    {
        return InnerProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(providerManifest, commandTree);
    }

    protected override string GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
    {
        return InnerProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(connection);
    }

    protected override DbProviderManifest GetDbProviderManifest(string manifestToken)
    {
        return InnerProviderServices.GetProviderManifest(manifestToken);
    }

    protected override DbSpatialDataReader GetDbSpatialDataReader(DbDataReader fromReader, string manifestToken)
    {
        return InnerProviderServices.GetSpatialDataReader(fromReader, manifestToken);
    }
}

public class TestDbConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
    private IDbConnectionFactory InnerDbConnectionFactory { get; set; }

    public TestDbConnectionFactory(IDbConnectionFactory inner)
    {
        InnerDbConnectionFactory = inner;
    }

    public DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        return InnerDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(nameOrConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Test Console App

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DbConfiguration.Loaded += (_, a) =>
        {
            a.ReplaceService<DbProviderServices>((s, k) => new TestDbProviderServices(s));
            a.ReplaceService<IDbConnectionFactory>((s, k) => new TestDbConnectionFactory(s));
        };

        var db = new TestEF6DataSource();
        var point = CreatePoint(1843503.54576196, 5743170.10983084);
        var shapes = db.MattShapes.Where(s => s.GeoShape.Intersects(point)).Select(s => s.MattShapeId).ToList();

        foreach (var shape in shapes)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(shape);
        }

        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static DbGeometry CreatePoint(double x, double y)
    {
        var text = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, "POINT({0} {1})", x, y);
        return DbGeometry.PointFromText(text, 0);
    }
}
```

I am using EF 6.0.1 via NuGet. I must be missing something fairly obvious but not sure what it is!

**Update**

Stack trace

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232004
  Message=An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__a()
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9()
       at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at EFWrapper.Console.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Projects\EFWrapper\EFWrapper.Console\Program.cs:line 28
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.ArgumentException
       HResult=-2147024809
       Message=Specified type is not registered on the target server.System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.
       Source=System.Data
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(_SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc, Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 startRpc, Int32 startParam)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClassb.<Reader>b__8()
            at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1 executing, Action`1 executed)
            at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
       InnerException:
```

**Update 2**

I have created a sample app on Skydrive that you can download and see the issue I am getting
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8062EC63AFF4490A!107

**Update 3**

The hack required to make the provider wrapper work is as follows

```
protected override void SetDbParameterValue(DbParameter parameter, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.TypeUsage parameterType, object value)
{
    /*
     * Hack
     * 
     * SetParameterValue is internal and am unable to call it on the InnerProviderServices from here. This breaks the provider wrapper when making
     * spatial queries in EF 6.0.1
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966106/spatial-datareader-and-wrapping-providers-in-ef6
     */
    if (InnerProviderServices == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException("InnerProviderServices must not be NULL");

    var setParameterValueMethod = InnerProviderServices.GetType().GetMethod("SetParameterValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    setParameterValueMethod.Invoke(InnerProviderServices, new[] { parameter, parameterType, value });
}
```

Comment: Any more info needed that would help us solve this issue? Once I have sorted I will write a blog post / tutorial highlighting what I have done wrong here :)

Comment: show the stacktrace and inner exceptions (if there are any)

Comment: stack trace added. I thought this was a very simple example but I must be missing something. The wrapped provider services returns the InnerProviderServices SpatialDataReader by calling GetSpatialDataReader. So, the wrapped provider should actually do nothing but return all the inner provider implementations?

Comment: I have not tried your repro but my gut feeling is that you don't have SqlTypes installed on your box. EF does not implement any spatial services itself but delegates calls to the underlying implementation. For SqlServer you would have to have SqlServer.Types.dll installed which contains the implementation (take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117008/net-4-5-beta-dbgeography-notimplementedexception/10131940#10131940). I might be wrong but from the stack trace it looks like SqlServer is treating DbGeometry as UDT as opposed to a native spatial type it should be translated to

Comment: @Pawel I have the clr types installed. I am running this from my dev machine and the instance of sql is running locally on the same machine. If you comment out the DbConfiguration.Loaded section, the code functions as normal (the spatial query is completed successfully) so that points to the wrapper provider service? Maybe I haven't overridden every method I needed to in my wrapper?

Comment: @Pawel I have added a sample app if that will help with diagnosing what is going on

Comment: Sorry it took so long. The repro was really helpful in nailing down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a bug in the provider model.  SqlProviderServices converts EDM spatial types to SqlServer spatial types in the SetParameterValue method however there is no public way to call this method from your wrapping provider. I created a bug for tracking this: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1867. An ugly workaround would be to call the internal SetParameterValue method using reflection.

Comment: Thanks! That certainly is the issue. I will update the original question with the hack workaround... at least until it is fixed in a later version of EF6