# DefaultSpatialServices.GeographyPolygonFromText Error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I recently installed VS2015 on a new machine and cloned my project from Git Hub.
When I try to run this code:

```
DbGeography.PolygonFromText(this.LATLNG, 4326); //latlng is text
```

I get this error

```
 System.NotImplementedException was unhandled
```

I went to nuget and installed

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

But this didn't help.

I have installed Sql Server 2016 dev on my machine as well so I thought that this would intall the dependencies.

Has anyone got a link so that I can download the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a dependency issue. The exception you are getting is most likely because the method you are calling has not been implemented (yet):

```
public static Polygon PolygonFromText(string latLong, int whatever)
{
     throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Without the stack trace I can't be sure 100%. Maybe the exception is being raised by some other method that is being called down the stack, but the reason is still the same; somewhere you are trying call functionality that symply is not there yet.

This is pretty usual in code bases still under development. It is frequently used in classes implementing interfaces or deriving from abstract base types to get the code into compilable state for testing purposes.

If its a final product then it would be questionable how this made it out into the public; a `NotSupportedException` would be the better choice.

Comment: On my original machine I have sql server 2012 installed - I will un-install 2016 and install 2014

Comment: @Pual Stanley Why do you think this is a sql server issue? Post the stack trace of the exception you are getting.

Comment: I believe that it is tied in with spacial types in entity framework.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117008/net-4-5-beta-dbgeography-notimplementedexception

Comment: @PaulStanley Wow, you seem to be right. That is a terrible exception to throw in this situation.

Comment: I agree with location based apps so prevalent. MS making life difficult.